# the purpose of .bak files in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java development and just saw a file with .bak extension that looks like a java class but it is not. So I am wondering what is the purpose of the .bak files in general and why and when should I use it?

Comment: Normally it's some kind of backup file. Google can give you more information.

Comment: In computing, `.bak` is a filename extension commonly used to signify a backup copy of a file.

Comment: Depending on what programs you use, they can be auto-generated when you change a file. For example, if you use WinMerge, and change one of the files whilst comparing, it will auto-create a yourfile.extension.bak file in the same location as the file (I guess, depending on the program settings).

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs guys. It helped.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special purpose for **java** files (or tooling here).

`bak` typically resorts to **backup**.

Such files get generated by various tools. These tools create bak files to avoid overwriting your original file. So there is no specific notion towards "java technology" here.

Simply look into the tools (mainly: your editor), and see if their help tells you about automatically creating backup file. The old Windows notepad editor did that for example.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat, a nice clear answer. I guess you can use a bak file to restore the original contents of your main file then?

Comment: That is the *idea*. But of course, if it works in practice depends on context. Some tools only keep a limited history, so the presence of a bak file *helps* restoring original content, but it is no guarantee.